# Looking for a Batchfile script to delete a folder when location is dynamic

Tags: batch-file

I want to delete all the contents of a folder (Google) across different systems from "C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Google" using a batch file, but across all systems username is different. So, is it possible to delete using a batch file without giving the exact location?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `forfiles` in the `C:\Users` directory, check if `@path` contains the "word" `Local\Google`, and put this in a batchfile. You put this batchfile on every server and add it to the task scheduler.

The `forfiles` feature is explained in this URL: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/forfiles